# Getting the latest value of duplicate keys in list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, filter, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries like this
UNFILTERED LIST OF DICTIONARIES:

```
[{'team': 'green', 'user': 'bob'}, {'play': '${bla/bla}', 'mentor': 'alice', 'team': 'blue'}, {'team': 'yellow'}]
```

i need to get FILTERED list with only last appeared key of duplicates like

FILTERED LIST:

```
[{'user': 'bob'}, {'play': '${bla/bla}', 'mentor': 'alice'}, {'team': 'yellow'}]
```

** key 'team' will keep only one and the latest value **

(it can be any duplicate key name that i couldn't know in advance so it should be general solution)

thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list from last to first dict, save all read keys in a extra list and if a key is already in the extra list delete it from current dict.

I am not so familiar with python but that should work:

```
myList = [{'team': 'green', 'user': 'bob'}, {'play': '${bla/bla}', 'mentor': 'alice', 'team': 'blue'}, {'team': 'yellow'}]
myList.reverse()
delList = []
for dict in myList:
    for key in list(dict.keys()):
        if key in delList:
            del dict[key]
        else:
            delList.append(key)
myList.reverse()
print(myList)
```

Comment: thank you! it's working perfectly for my case. Reverse read of dict is a great way.

Comment: pL4Gu33, may be you can clarify me this error       
elif isinstance(v, dict):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types 

something is running wrong now for my first dict handling, when i run script twice...